# 1st order q-differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, q-analogs, quantum-calculus

Can we solve 1st order q-differential equations using the usual methods of 1st order differential equations? For example, can we use integration factor method to solve this q-differential equations?

$$\text D_qy(x)=a(x)y(qx)+b(x)$$

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to get a functional equation since you asked. Starting with a direct reference from [q-Derivative from Wolfram MathWorld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-Derivative.html):

> [image]

Therefore:

$$\text D_q y(x)=a(x)y(qx)+b(x)=\frac{y(qx)-y(x)}{x(q-1)}=a(x) y(qx)+b(x)$$

which works for $q\ne 1$ since:

$$\lim_{q\to1}\text  D_q y(x)= \lim_{q\to1} \frac{y(qx)-y(x)}{x(q-1)} =\lim_{q\to0}\frac{y(x+q)-y(x)}{q}=y’(x)= \text D y(x)=\frac{dy(x)}{dx}$$

but this limit is not needed when the q-Derivative is taken. Therefore we have our functional equation, rewritten:

$$\boxed{\text D_q y(x)=a(x)y(qx)+b(x)\iff\frac{y(qx)-y(x)}{x(q-1)}=a(x) y(qx)+b(x)}$$

Here is another form which also gives a recursive solution:

$$\text D_q y(x)=a(x)y(qx)+b(x)\iff y(qx)-y(x)=a(x) y(qx)x(q-1)+b(x)x(q-1)\\\implies y(x)=y(qx)(a(x)x(1-q)+1)-b(x)x(q-1) $$

Please correct me and give me feedback!

Comment: Now I understand what you meant about the functional equation! And yes I did this by repeating the recurrence relation.

Comment: @LAMAS.M In short, does this help or was it something that you already knew about?

Comment: When I posted the question I was curious if there's a particular solution to the qDE other than a recursive solution. But you helped when you explained the functional equation.